# How can I copy the values from a vector to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How can I get the `dValues[]` in the line `double dValues[] = {what should i input here?}`?Because I'm using an array. The goal is to get the mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

double GetMode(double daArray[], int iSize) {
// Allocate an int array of the same size to hold the
// repetition count
int* ipRepetition = new int[iSize];
for (int i = 0; i < iSize; ++i) {
    ipRepetition[i] = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool bFound = false;
    while ((j < i) && (daArray[i] != daArray[j])) {
        if (daArray[i] != daArray[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
    }
    ++(ipRepetition[j]);
}
int iMaxRepeat = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < iSize; ++i) {
    if (ipRepetition[i] > ipRepetition[iMaxRepeat]) {
        iMaxRepeat = i;
    }
}
delete [] ipRepetition;
return daArray[iMaxRepeat];
}


int main()  
{
int count, minusElements; 
float newcount, twocount;
cout << "Enter Elements:";
std::cin >> count;
std::vector<float> number(count);




cout << "Enter " << count << " number:\n";
for(int i=0; i< count ;i++)  
{
   std::cin >> number[i];
}

double dValues[] = {};
int iArraySize = count;

std::cout << "Mode = "
            << GetMode(dValues, iArraySize) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: on line: double dValues[] = {}; on the parenthesis, what should i input there to get the variables that i input?

Answer (score 2):

You already have all the values in your `number` vector, but if you wanted to copy those values into a new array called `dValues`, you have to allocate it on the heap (since you don't know the size at compile-time), copy the elements from the vector, and later free up that memory:

```c++
double *dValues = new double[number.size()];

for (size_t i = 0; i < number.size(); i++)
{
    dValues[i]  = number[i];
}

// whatever you need to do with dValues

delete [] dValues;
```

You're also not checking that you're within the bounds of your vector in the `for` loop. A safer implementation would use the `push_back()` method on the `vector` rather than assigning the values by index.

Comment: thank you to all of you.. i got it now..

Comment: If so, you should give the helpful answers some credit in the form of up-votes and/or accepting an answer. This is how the community rewards those who put the time in to give quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wish to copy the elements from the vector to array. If yes -

```
 float *dValues = new float[count] ; // Need to delete[] when done
 std::copy( number.begin(), number.end(), dValues );
```

[std::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) is in algorithms header. But why do you want to use/create raw array for this task. You already have the vector `number` and just pass it to `GetMode(..)`

Comment: coz i dont really i understand abot std: etc.. and i just want to study about getting mean, median and mode using array..